# PluginNotFoundException - MailChimp

Tags: 8, emails

Earlier today I tried to install the MailChimp plugin for Drupal 8. I couldn't get it working properly so I decided I would just go ahead and uninstall it.

However, when I navigate to `/admin/modules/uninstall` I get the following error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>
> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "filter_mailchimp_campaign" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 57 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).
>
> Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('filter_mailchimp_campaign')
> Drupal\filter\FilterPluginCollection->initializePlugin('filter_mailchimp_campaign')
> Drupal\Component\Plugin\LazyPluginCollection->get('filter_mailchimp_campaign')
> Drupal\filter\FilterPluginCollection->get('filter_mailchimp_campaign')
> Drupal\filter\FilterPluginCollection->sortHelper('filter_align', 'filter_mailchimp_campaign')
> uasort(Array, Array)
> Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultLazyPluginCollection->sort()
> Drupal\filter\FilterPluginCollection->sort()
> Drupal\filter\Entity\FilterFormat->filters()
> Drupal\filter\FilterUninstallValidator->validate('filter')
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->validateUninstall(Array)
> Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->validateUninstall(Array)
> Drupal\system\Form\ModulesUninstallForm->buildForm(Array, Object)
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm('system_modules_uninstall', Object)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object)
> Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> call_user_func_array(Object, Array)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object)

Likewise, when I try and go to edit any pages content, I get the same error. This is preventing me from doing anything. I went ahead and uninstalled the plugin manually be removing all of the mailchimp files from the modules directory over FTP but I am still getting this error.

Any ideas on what I need to do to fix this? It's driving me crazy!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this. I had to go into the database and manually delete the entry `filter.mailchimp_campaing` from the `config` table.